# Generating a new variable by selection from multiple variables

Tags: stata

I have some data on diseases and age of diagnosis.  Each participant was asked what diseases they have had and at what age that disease was diagnosed.
There are a set of variables `disease1-28`   with  a numeric code for each disease and another set `age1-28` with the age at diagnosis in years. The diseases are placed in successive variables in the order recalled; the age of diagnosis is placed in the appropriate age variable.

I would like to generate a new variable for each of several diseases giving the age of diagnosis of that disease: e.g. `asthma_age_at_diagnosis`

Can I do this without having 28 `replace` statements?

Example of the data:

```
+-------------+----------+----------+----------+------+------+------+  
| Participant | Disease1 | Disease2 | Disease3 | Age1 | Age2 | Age3 |  
+-------------+----------+----------+----------+------+------+------+    
|           1 |      123 | 3        | .        |   30 | 2    | .    |  
|           2 |      122 | 123      | 5        |   23 | 51   | 44   |  
|           3 |        5 | .        | .        |   50 | .    | .    |  
+-------------+----------+----------+----------+------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give a general heads-up that a question of this form without any code of your own is often considered off-topic for Stack Overflow. Still, the Stata users around here are the people answering Stata questions (surprise) and we usually indulge questions like this if interesting and well-posed.

I'd advise a different data structure, period. With your example data

```
clear 
input Patient Disease1 Disease2 Disease3 Age1 Age2 Age3 
1 123 3 . 30 2 . 
2 122 123 5 23 51 44 
3 5 . . 50 . . 
end
```

You can `reshape`

```
reshape long Disease Age, i(Patient) j(Order)
drop if missing(Disease)
list, sep(0) 

   +--------------------------------+
   | Patient  Order   Disease   Age |
   |--------------------------------|
1. |       1      1       123    30 |
2. |       1      2         3     2 |
3. |       2      1       122    23 |
4. |       2      2       123    51 |
5. |       2      3         5    44 |
6. |       3      1         5    50 |
   +--------------------------------+
```

With the data in this form you can now answer lots of questions easily. I don't see that a whole bunch of new variables would make many analyses easier. Another way to see this is that you have hinted that the order in which diseases are coded is arbitrary; that being so, wiring that into the data structure is ill-advised. Even if order is important, it is still accessible as part of the dataset (variable `Order`).

Hint: If you still want separate variables for some purposes, look at `separate`.